# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404

Tags: jquery, url, path, liferay

I am using [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) in [Liferay Portal](http://www.liferay.com) as a PHP portlet and when I upload a file I get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://localhost:8080/server/php/
```

My project tree:

```
Upload-portlet
    |
    |___docroot
            |
            |__ cors
            |__ css
            |__ img
            |__ js
                |__ main.js (that contains url to server/php/)

            |__ META-INF
            |__ server
            |       |__ php
            |
            |__ WEB-INF
            | 
            |   view.php
```

I tested the *jQuery File Upload* in [Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/it/index.html) and it works fine. I only copied the files from Xampp to my portlet and I deployed it without getting any error. Then when I upload a file I get erro status `404` on `http://localhost:8080/server/php/`

I tried to change `url` to *absolute path*:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/Upload-portlet/server/php/'
});
```

and *relative path*:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '../server/php/'
});
```

But I still get HTTP status 404.

---

## Update:

thanks to [Martin Gamulin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196134/martin-gamulin) I solved the problem: I changed my url to `url: '/Upload-portlet/server/php/index.php'` and the problem of 404 is no longer occurring.

But even if I solved this problem, the file is not uploaded (I do not get any error). I see in the *Chrome JavaScript Console* that when I upload a file the call return 200 status (OK).

[image]

But when I go to folder `F:\LIFERAY\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\Upload-portlet\server\php\files` where images are saved I find it empty. And in the preview (see the screenshot below) I get php code instead of thumbnail.

[image]

Now the problem is that Liferay/Tomcat ***is not interpreting PHP*** file that has not been declared in the `portlet.xml`. **view.php** is interpreted probably because it has been declared in the xml.

```
<portlet-class>com.liferay.util.bridges.php.PHPPortlet</portlet-class>
<init-param>
    <name>view-uri</name>
    <value>/view.php</value>
</init-param>
```

I tried to put all the php code inside *view.php* but it still does not work. I verified that PHP works on *view.php* with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and I get all the informations about PHP. The output here:

   **Quercus**

```
PHP Version => 5.2.0
System => Windows 7 6.1 amd64
Build Date => 20070628T2777
Configure Command => n/a
Server API => CGI
Virtual Directory Support => disabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => WEB-INF/php.ini
PHP API => 20031224
PHP Extension => 20041030
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => enabled
Registered PHP Streams => php, file, http, https
```

**PHP Variables**

```
Variable    Value
_REQUEST["COOKIE_SUPPORT"]   true
_REQUEST["COMPANY_ID"]   10204
_REQUEST["ID"]   6d49557674326c5142786c793578787233502b346b513d3d
_REQUEST["USER_UUID"]    40LHv8GLWffkS2XSYCqE61YcYleKtJSSpCdYnMZF3J0=
_REQUEST["GUEST_LANGUAGE_ID"]    en_US
_REQUEST["LFR_SESSION_STATE_10248"]  expired
_REQUEST["JSESSIONID"]   24CB07F376E4A7BCE991812360AFF4C1
_GET["portlet_namespace"]    _Upload_WAR_Uploadportlet_
_GET["portlet_name"]     Upload

etc..
```

I am trying now to change the `get_full_url()` (in the PHP *class UploadHandler*) to another url probably it messes with the Liferay urls.
Thank you for any help and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What is your php script called. You should probably want to change your url to something like http://localhost:8080/Upload-portlet/server/php/whatever-my-upload-script-is-named.php

Comment: Thank you so much! problem solved, but the upload doesn't work on Liferay.

Comment: What is happening now? Do you have anything related in log files?

Comment: You can download the war of my portlet [here](http://ge.tt/3U3hHvN1/v/0?c) for Liferay 6.2, if anyone wants to check what the problem.